# How do I improve the soundproofing between two rooms?

Tags: sound-proofing

I wamt to improve the soundproofing of a wall shared by 2 rooms. At the moment, I can hear the TV, conversations, etc, from my brother's room. The TV and conversations are extremely clear; I can make out exactly what's being said which is annoying and distracting when trying to sleep.

Some things to be aware of:

- We live in a maisonette inside a block of flats (UK style).
- We don't own the property but the rules about home improvements are fairly liberal as it's an ex-council property.
- If anyone has any experience of getting landlords to do this kind of work, that'd be excellent (landlord is a housing association).
- Knocking down and rebuilding the wall with soundproofing is not an option

I saw a YouTube video about making holes in the wall and then filling it with insulation, but don't remember what that technique is and can't find the video anymore

Any ideas would be welcome

Answer (score 3):

You could cut some holes in the drywall and use some blow in insulation. Something like dense-pack cellulose.

What helps even more is to then glue another layer of drywall with something like [green glue](http://www.greengluecompany.com/).

Answer (score 0):

In order to improve sound proofing, you may go for sound proof wall panels. The panels block the sound and prevent it from transmitting it to the other room.

Comment: This may be a slightly more expensive but less labor intense option to try. With panels on both sides of the wall it could work quite well.